# Regex: trouble checking if a line doesn't end in a word

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

As I wrote above, I want to GET (sorry I wrote check) a line if it doesn't end in a specific word ("done.") and it starts with this characters: "[-]".

Example:

```
[-] Blabla bla bla. [✓]
[*] Blabla bla done. [X]
[.] Bla bla bla done. [X]
```

This is my try:

```
   /\[-\](.*)[^done\.]$/gmi
```

Do you know how I can do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @adeneo, I want to search the lines which don't end in "done.". That's the opposite, isn't it?

Comment: @adeneo like this  `/^\[.+[^done\.]$/`   ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just with this:

```
/^\[-\](?!.*\bdone\.(?:[\n\r]|$))/mgi
```

`(?!.*\bdone\.(?:[\n\r]|$))` is negative lookahead. Checking that the line is not ending with `done.`

`^[-]` is checking that the hyphen is at the beginning of the string.

`\b` is a word boundary, so that it doesn't pick words like `xyzdone.`

`(?:[\n\r]|$)` is checking either end of string, or at line breaks.

Comment: Hello Sabuj, I checked your option but it doesn't work.

Check this regex running: http://regexr.com/38lkm

Comment: @Daniel976034 I updated my answer several times. May be you picked older one. Can you please copy again from my answer?

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! But I don't get all the line. I'm sorry because I don't mentioned it, but how can I get all the line or the text after "[-]". Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel976034 Just add `.*` at the end of your regex and it will do. http://regexr.com/38lm0

Comment: Wow it was really easy!, thank you very much for your time. I appreciate a lot your answer and I have to learn seriously REGEX! it can't be my Achilles heel :)

Thank you again for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged it as [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), you can do the below:

```
function check(input,word)
{
  return /^\[-].+/.test(input) && !new RegExp(word +"$").test(input);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
check('[-] e3r34 done.','done.'); // false
check('[-] e3r34 not.','done.'); // true
```